# Get friends from facebook javascript api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Currenly i am using facebook javascript version 2.0 to get friends. but it only returns friends which are using app and not all friends.

FB.api(
    "/me/friends",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);

I tried the graph api explorer it is still returning friends using app and not all friends.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. Facebook changed this in the 2.0 version, it's a "privacy issue"

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog